# No space between bottom of screen and footer div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am having issues with creating a space between the bottom of the screen and the last div.

In Chrome, no problems, but with IE the border is right at the bottom of the screen.

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="header">...</div>
 <div id="main">...</div>
 <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

The last div only has `<br />`'s

Here is the css...

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   top:30px;
   left:15px;
   width:60%;   
   border:black solid 1px;
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {    
   padding:0px;
}
#body {
   background-color:FAF0E6;
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:25px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:10px;
   width:100%;
   height:25px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
```

---

Like I said, works great in Chrome, but not so much in IE.

What I would like is a space at the top and the bottom of the screen.

Edit- As an added note, I don't even see the bottom border in IE.

Thanks for the help,

-Kris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace min-height:100% by height:100% in #container. Works in IE8.

EDIT: Is this what you are looking for?

```
html {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
body {
   background-color:FAF0E6;
   margin-top:35px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
#container {
   left:15px;
   width:60%;   
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {    
   padding:0px;
}

#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:10px;
   width:100%;
   height:25px;
}
```

Comment: that still didn't seem to work...seems to throw Chrome for a loop as well.

Comment: This is a lot closed to what I was trying to achieve.  Actually it gave me space between the bottom of the screen and the div.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try adding `border-bottom: solid #FFFFFF 10px;` to the body style. Works for me in IE8.

Comment: I still don't see any space created.  I added `margin-bottom:25px;` to the code.